# Basecamp3 Chrome-extensions 'turbolinks:load' not firing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, basecamp

```
console.log('messages-list script loaded');

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
    console.log('turbolinks:load');
});
```

I'm trying to listen to this event but it is not firing in my script.js.
If I paste this in console of chrome browser then it works. Only first console.log statement works.

Comment: Check [context selector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context) in console toolbar - does it say "top"?

Comment: Yes, it say "top". If I reload the page then the listener defined in my script.js file works.

Comment: Can't tell the exact cause but you can run that code in [page context](/q/9515704/), which is the same environment used when running in devtools console with the default context ("top").